# Delphi QuickReport not printing title (and other bands)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, quickreports

What are the reasons for QuickReport not to print bands? Missing the title and detail. Prints only page footer and summary, any ideas?

Comment: Without the actual code of your report and its associated DFM it is really difficult to say. Are both bands enabled/visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only two ways to not print a band in QuickReport is to set it's **Enabled** property to False (stored in DFM or by code before the band is actually printed) and to write a OnBeforePrint event handler which in turn sets the **PrintBand** parameter to False.  That said by memory, the parameter name may be different, but for that propose.

If you are sure you're doing neither of this, I suggest you inspect the values for the referred property/method at runtime (the closest the print moment, the better) and if they are *changed* from what you set by dfm/code look at memory corruption problems on your application.

Answer (score 0):

The empty bands were not printed. After connecting the DB QuickReport labels to the dataset, the band was printing.